# Can't get into a directory

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, spyder

```
for file in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\plant_tomato_leaf_dataset\plantvillage'):
    for cl in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\plant_tomato_leaf_dataset\plantvillage\\'+file):
        print(file)
        print(cl)
    print('******************')
```

**I have a folder "plantvillage". Inside that folder I have 10 folder. I have to access all the sub-folders and perform operations on those sub-folder-items. But this code is showing only items of the first folder**

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in `os.walk` instead of `os.listdir`. `listdir` is not recursive.

An example would be:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\plant_tomato_leaf_dataset\plantvillage'):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(root,file))
```

this will run the inner loop as many times as there are directories, and will also check to make sure that each file is actually a file. If you want to look at the directories themselves for some reason (ignoring files), you can do that like so:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\plant_tomato_leaf_dataset\plantvillage'):
    for directory in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root,directory))
```

but don't try to mix and match. Getting the current directory is easy when iterating files. It's just `root`.